# How to identify the Requests received in azure API management

Tags: azure-api-management

we have an production issue where the order is submitted twice. Currently we have an API for order and we are exposing this to client using API management and in these we have policies for URL mapping for customer facing  to actual .

Now , our actual API got 2 request  so we thought customer submitted twice but they have confirmed that they have not submitted twice , so either there is issue with API management which fired 2 request.

How can i Identify the request received by the API management ? 
Is there any chance that API management will fire the request twice ?

Appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fire request twice in APIM would be by the means of Retry policy or manually using SendRequest. Otherwise it should be a client calling your API two times. Each request in APIM get it's own unique id accessible in policies as context.RequestId, this is the main way to track and identify them. But these ids are produced inside APIM itself thus are useful only if you're tracking a call from APIM and into backend.

Your best option now is to try to identify requests by client ip, method, uri, and time frame. APIM allows you to grab logs for certain periods of time (better if kept short) in JSON or CSV with data I mentioned above. To do that look into byRequest report (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/reports#ReportByRequest), grab JSON/CSV and try to identify calls of interest,

For future you could look into onboarding your service to azure monitor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor) or log analytics those provide easier way to traverse logs.